# Postman test error while trying to check if JSON field value is not null or undefined

Tags: json, testing, postman

I'm trying to create a test for a GET request in Postman to check if the value stored in the 'name' field  of each object is different from **null** and **undefined**, but I get the following message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"
This is an example of the JSON body I'm working with:

```
[
{
 "id":1,
 "name": "Peter"
},
{
 "id":2,
 "name":"Stewie" 
},
{
 "id":3,
 "name":"Brian"
}
]
```

And this is the JS code for the test:

```
pm.test(``, function(){ 
    var response = JSON.parse(responseBody)
    var result = true

    for (i=0;i<=response.length;i++){ 
    if(!response[i].name){
     result = false}
    }
    pm.expect(result).to.eql(true)
});
```

Things I've tried:

1. Getting the JSON body using
   `var jsonData = pm.response.json();`
   instead of
    `var response = JSON.parse(responseBody)`
2. Using the following condition for the **IF** statement:
   `!response[i]['name']`
3. Storing the 'name' value in a global variable as follows:

```
    pm.test(``, function(){ 
        var response = JSON.parse(responseBody)
        var result = true
    
        for (i=0;i<=response.length;i++){ 
         pm.globals.set("variable_name", response[i]['name'];
         var name = pm.globals.get("variable_name");
        if(!name){
         result = false}
        }
        pm.expect(result).to.eql(true)
       });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you not just checking for what the type that it is and if it's not that type, it will fail? `pm.expect(response[i].name).to.be.a('string');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its a array out of index error , you are checking i till it is equal it response.lenght

so last value will be response[response.length] , there is no element last element is response[response.length-1] . So just remove equal from for loop

```
pm.test(``, function(){ 
    var response = JSON.parse(responseBody)
    var result = true

    for (i=0;i<response.length;i++){ 
    if(!response[i].name){
     result = false}
    }
    pm.expect(result).to.eql(true)
});
```

But the right way to do it is to do schema valdiaiton:

```
let schema = {
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "$id": "http://example.com/example.json",
    "type": "array",
    "title": "The root schema",
    "description": "The root schema comprises the entire JSON document.",
    "default": [],
    "examples": [
        [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Peter"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Stewie"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "additionalItems": true,
    "items": {
        "$id": "#/items",
        "anyOf": [
            {
                "$id": "#/items/anyOf/0",
                "type": "object",
                "title": "The first anyOf schema",
                "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
                "default": {},
                "examples": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Peter"
                    }
                ],
                "required": [
                    "id",
                    "name"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "$id": "#/items/anyOf/0/properties/id",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "title": "The id schema",
                        "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
                        "default": 0,
                        "examples": [
                            1
                        ]
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "$id": "#/items/anyOf/0/properties/name",
                        "type": "string",
                        "title": "The name schema",
                        "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
                        "default": "",
                        "examples": [
                            "Peter"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "additionalProperties": true
            }
        ]
    }
}


pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
     pm.response.to.have.jsonSchema(schema);
});
```

You can generate schema using : https://jsonschema.net/home

Postman output when name is null :

[image]

Comment: It just doesn't feel like the way to attack the problem and a really messy way to find the answer. In my opinion.

Comment: Yes danny just over engineering the things

Comment: The best approach is to do schema validation with type string , it will throw error if the data is null

Comment: @DannyDainton added that to answer

Comment: @PDHide Obviously *facepalm* ... I've completely missed that out. Thanks!